# How to subtract the moving-average results from the corresponding original values?

Tags: r, zoo, moving-average

This line given below will simply calculate the moving average for certain values with a window of 3. As the total number of values is 12 and the moving-average widow is 3, the number of resulted values is 10 (as shown below).

```
library(zoo)
x <- c(1,2,3,NA,NA,4,6,5,6,4,2,5)
movingmean <- rollapply(x, 3, FUN = mean, na.rm = T)
movingmean
#  [1] 2.000000 2.500000 3.000000 4.000000 5.000000 5.000000
#  [7] 5.666667 5.000000 4.000000 3.666667
```

I want to subtract these averages (`movingmean`) from the corresponding original value.

**Example:** `2-2.000000, 3-2.500000, NA-3.000000, NA-4.000000, ..., 2-3.666667`.

Comment: `x-movingmean` should do it

Comment: `x[seq_along(movingmean)] - movingmean`

Comment: zoo automatically aligns zoo objects when performing arithmetic on them so: `z <- zoo(x); rollapply(z, 3, mean, na.rm = TRUE) - z` would do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, `rollapply` does not pad the result with `NA`.  Set `fill=NA` to do so.

```
movingmean <- rollapply(x, 3, FUN=mean, na.rm=TRUE, fill=NA)
x - movingmean
#  [1]         NA  0.0000000  0.5000000         NA         NA
#  [6] -1.0000000  1.0000000 -0.6666667  1.0000000  0.0000000
# [11] -1.6666667         NA
```

Also note that `rollapply` uses a centered window by default.  You can change it via the `align` argument or use `rollapplyr` if you want a right-aligned calculation (as with most time series).

Answer (score 1):

You can change mean function to :

```
library(zoo)
x <- c(1,2,3,NA,NA,4,6,5,6,4,2,5)
> rollapply(x, 3, FUN = function(x) (x-mean(x))[2])
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
x[seq_along(movingmean)+1] - movingmean

# [1]  0.0000000  0.5000000         NA         NA -1.0000000  1.0000000 
#        -0.6666667  1.0000000  0.0000000 -1.6666667
```